# How do I call all the other functions in main which are in another CPP file

Tags: c++, header-files

I have created a .CPP file (which also has main() and where all functions are called) and a .h file (where all the functions are written in a class) .I don't know how to link them together.

Comment: #include "your_file_name" should do the work for you. You do not need to call the cpp files, only the header files need to be included.

Comment: I had included filename.h in cpp file  but when I try to run it, it doesnot show any output.

Comment: You need to include it in .cpp file as well as main.cpp

Comment: any other header files should I add ??and my cpp file is my main cpp file .I mean I have one .h file which has main() function .and another .cpp file. but if I add filename.h in the .h file it shows error.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your files?

Comment: You need to show your files, and since you mention linking also show the commands you are using to compile & link.

Answer (score 0):

*include"yourfilename.h" your main.cpp file
Also write this include in other .cpp files where you had implement the functions of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The simple file structure for a program with header files should be like this:

> filename.h

```
/*
Your Function Declarations
*/
```

> filename.cpp

```
 #include"filename.h"
 /* -Functions Declared in filename.h would be implemented here
  Your Function Implementations
 */
```

> main.cpp

```
#include"filename.h"

int main(){

}
```